# How to turn off or temporarily disable Visual Studio code hints when hover over code with cursor

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Started using Visual Studio for Flutter.  It always shows debug messages whenever cursor is hovering over code which I admit are useful, however, many times it's a struggle just to type a character of code in a line as the messages are preventing insertion of code for seconds at a time and it's becoming annoying.

Every message board I see says go to Visual Studio / tools / etc. to turn off such messages. But I see no such menu item, I see: File Selection View Terminal Run Go Help.

How to turn off these pesky messages so I can get back to typing code without having to coninuously fight Microsoft for control of my editor.